# Cannot hear live audio from USB guitar in GarageBand

Tags: macos, garageband

I plugged guitar via USB external audio card U24XL to Mac OS X Yosemite. But I can't hear any sound of it in GarageBand. I set up input/output in GB's preferences, and marked the current (guitar) track for monitoring, but no sound of guitar is listenable, nor recordable.

Output is correct as I can hear a drum track. The audio card works fine because I can monitor raw guitar sound via a tiny utility `LineIn` (I can record it in `Audition` also).

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Your image shows "U24XL with SPDIF I/O" for GarageBand's Input Device selection. Is there an option that doesn't mention SPDIF? I'm not familiar with the U24XL, but I've looked at a picture, and I suspect SPDIF is the optical connections, not the analog jacks.

Comment: There are two inputs (spdif and analog) in that card. But I think it's just a title for the card. Anyway there is just one output in it.